# How to customize magento top links

Tags: magento-1.7

Is there any tutorial for top links or top menu.I want to customize top links.
please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: what type of customize?you want to add links or remove existing link?

Comment: There is a lot of variability in the approach which you take. You should describe your desired outcome so that you can get an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom link by adding following code in local.xml file -

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>My Link</label>
        <url>path/to/page</url>
        <title>My link tooltip</title>
        <prepare>true</prepare>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>150</position>
        <liParams>id="my-custom-id"</liParams>
    </action>
</reference>
```

check out this for refernce: http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/editing-magentos-top-links-the-better-way